# Excel VBA formatting a closed Worksheet Error 1004 "Application Defined or Object Defined Error"

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a big pile of VBA code and unfortunately the simplest part of it will not work. All I need is to open a specific workbook (name will not change) and draw borders in it. My Sub to write to it works fine, but as soon as I try and draw any borders it draws them in the Worksheet that the VBA code is associated with, not the one it has opened. The below code was my attempt to fix it (I've moved it to its own Sub for convenience) but the error 1004 kicks in on `ActiveSheet.Range(rRng).BorderAround xlContinuous`

I don't doubt this is something obvious, but I cannot for the life of me see where it is. E.g. `xl0.ActiveSheet.Range(rangeAA) = CardDataInputMode` this works absolutely fine for me in the WriteToSheet Sub I created, but adding the next line: `ActiveSheet.Range(rRng).BorderAround xlContinuous` will not work.    Out of curiosity I added `xl0.ActiveSheet.Range("A:AS").Columns.AutoFit` to the Write Sub and it AutoFits fine too. I'm going around in circles!

Here is the entire Sub, anything else needed please let me know! Many thanks.

```
Sub OutlineCells()
    Dim xl0 As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlw As New Excel.Workbook
    Dim rRng As Range
    Dim row As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set xlw = xl0.Workbooks.Open(Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Outputs\MasterCardTestCaseTemplate.xlsx")
    xlw.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A1:AS25")

    'Clear existing
    'rRng.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone

    For Each row In rRng.Rows
        For Each cell In row.Cells
            'Apply new borders
            xlw.ActiveSheet.Range(rRng).BorderAround xlContinuous  ' <--- ERROR HERE
            xlw.ActiveSheet.Range(rRng).Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            xlw.ActiveSheet.Range(rRng).Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Next cell
    Next row

    xlw.Save
    xlw.Close

    Set xl0 = Nothing
    Set xlw = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code keeps referencing `xl0` rather than `xlw` I think....

Comment: @JohnBustos thanks for the quick reply, changing to xlw causes the same error. It's a new language for me so I'm a bit muddled. As I said things like `xl0.ActiveSheet.Range(rangeT).NumberFormat = "@"` work absolutely fine, but this sub will not work at all. I don't doubt it's something right under my nose tbh.

Comment: @JohnBustos Thanks again, you were (of course) right in what you said, the confusion (from me) was due to it working before without xlw being used, however, that was sheer fluke as I was only using one CELL and not a full range so it didn't error (as per the answer below). I never would have caught that to be honest. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Glad you got it working - David's answer is pretty awesome and thorough, so hope it helps you learn more! - Good luck!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using your range object(s) incorrectly -- you have it in parentheses which causes an *evaluation*, and since the range object's default property is its `.Value`, this line:

```
xl0.ActiveSheet.Range(rRng).BorderAround xlContinuous
```

Is essentially this:

```
xl0.ActiveSheet.Range(rRng.Value).BorderAround xlContinuous
```

This would only *not* raise an error if `rRng` represents a single cell *and* that cell's `.Value` is a valid Address string.

Now, you could do this to force the `.Address` property:

```
xl0.ActiveSheet.Range(rRng.Address).BorderAround xlContinuous
```

But it would be better to qualify `rRng` to be part of the `xlW` workbook.  **Change this** so that it qualifies based on the `xlw` workbook:

```
Set rRng = xlw.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AS25")
```

Then you can use that range directly:

```
For Each row In rRng.Rows
    For Each cell In row.Cells
        'Apply new borders
        rRng.BorderAround xlContinuous  ' <--- ERROR HERE
        rRng.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        rRng.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    Next cell
Next row
```

Now that I look at it, you don't need that nested loop at all, just omit both `For Each` loops, I think this should do the same results:

```
'## DELETE THIS For Each row In rRng.Rows   
'## DELETE THIS   For Each cell In row.Cells
        'Apply new borders
        rRng.BorderAround xlContinuous  ' <--- ERROR HERE
        rRng.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        rRng.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
 '## DELETE THIS    Next cell
 '## DELETE THIS Next row
```

Comment: First off, many thanks for your reply. However, `Set rRng = xlw.Sheet1.Range("A1:AS25")` Object does not support this property or method. I'm not sure what I've overlooked.

Comment: Try `xlw.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AS25")`

Comment: Ah, my fault, I didn't see the changes you made in your edit to my question also. The `xlw.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AS25")` worked perfectly. I really appreciate your help, the lines worked before as I was only writing one cell at a time, not drawing across a range, so one error actually worked right caused a lot of confusion. Many, many thanks! You've saved me hours of confusion, and possibly making the whole project worse!

Comment: You actually don't even need the loops. See addendum to my answer

Comment: Even better! Great, many thanks accepted and upvoted. Just wanted to say thanks again! I've gone a bit loop mad with all this. I'd say a huge refactoring is in order down the line.  I think my brain just melted when writing this! Time to go outside and consume as much caffeine as is medically possible! I owe you one! (I'm in a new job not as a programmer writing code in a language I don't know!)

Comment: You're welcome! This site is a pretty good resource when you get stuck. Cheers!